# Finding all combinations of a list

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

My list is[1,1,1,2,2,2] and the total combinations are 20 including input list
The output should be like
[1,1,2,1,2,2]
[1,2,1,2,1,2]
So on 
Up to 20 combinations
The combinations must not be repititive
Someone pls help me to find a solution

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate all permutations of a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Python by default provides methods to help us find the permutations and combinations of a sequence. They come in a package known as `itertools`.

1. first you will have to import `permutations`:

   ```
   from itertools import permutations
   ```
2. Assuming that your list is stored in `x`

   i.e `x=[1,1,1,2,2,2]`
3. Take any other variable. eg: `P`

   ```
   P= permutations(x)
   ```

   [`P` is basically a list of all the different permutations of the list `x`]
4. ```
   for i in list(P):
       print(i)
   ```

   You'll have the different combinations.

Source: GeeksforGeeks

Comment: That's so informative,but do you have any idea about the source code of permutations function ,i want to know more about it